# How to post complex object from react to node via Axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, express, axios

I am a beginner and I am trying to update a record with a nested object via axios, from react :

Here is my function, which I have tried so many stuff to make it work, but no chances. You can see few of them as commented out.

```
    const saveBlend = async (layout, blocks) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            data: {
                layouts: layout,
                //layouts: toJSON(layout), ---> From Flatted
                //layouts: stringify(layout), ---> From Flatted
                //layouts: JSON.stringify(layout),
                //blocks: blocks,
                title: 'Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            //headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            url: '/blend/' + blendId,
        })

        console.log(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.response) {
            console.log(err.response.data.message)
        } else {
            console.log(err.message, 'Something went wrong.')
        }
    }
}
```

The object (layout) is coming from a react state and looks like this :

```
{
lg: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
md: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
sm: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
xs: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
xxs:[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```

Or this :

```
const userBlocks = [
    { i: 'b20e4586-b676-447c-9824-b6a9b61115bd', comp: 'Sample', x: 0, y: 0, w: 5, h: 2 },
    { i: '119bf4b4-8689-4ac2-bdd3-a16feb28d548', comp: 'Sample', x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 },
    { i: 'f9a70559-0ffe-45eb-aabf-549af484cc80', comp: 'Sample', x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
    { i: 'e49c1430-9a0b-418a-9312-986e8ff573bb', comp: 'Sample', x: 0, y: 2, w: 2, h: 2 },
    { i: 'b8af2e33-8a4a-482c-843d-b07691e35865', comp: 'Sample', x: 0, y: 2, w: 6, h: 2 },
```

]

At backend, when I try to read the sent value, it is undefined. Backend looks like this :

```
router.put('/:id', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const requestedUpdates = Object.keys(req.body)
        const allowedUpdates = ['layouts', 'blocks', 'home', 'title']
        const isUpdatePossible = requestedUpdates.every((update) => {
            return allowedUpdates.includes(update)
        })

        //console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.blocks))
        console.log(req.body.layouts)
        // console.log(req.body.blocks)
        // console.log(req.body.title)

        if (!isUpdatePossible) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Some of the requested fields is not possible to update' })
        }

        const url = req.params.id
        // const task = await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, req.body, { new: true, runValidators: true })

        const blend = await Blend.findOne({ url: req.params.id, user: req.user[0]._id })

        if (!blend) {
            return res.status(404).send({ message: 'The blend can not be found' })
        }

        requestedUpdates.forEach((update) => {
            blend[update] = req.body[update]
        })

        await blend.save()

        res.status(201).send(blend)
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.name == 'CastError') {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid blend URL' })
        }
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
})
```

So, my question is : **How can I put, patch, post these kind of complex data to my backend without any issues? So I can read and save to my DB after processing?**

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Please update your question with 1. an example of what your data might actually look like, 2. how you are trying to read it on the backend. From what you've shared there's nothing too complex to send on a http call.

Comment: @windowsill Thanks for your time. I have added the backend part, and also an actual array that I am trying to send, along with the structure of another data which is a nested object.

Answer (score 0):

The [req.body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

Server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.put('/some/path', (req, res) => {
  console.log('data from the client', req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Client code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.put('http://localhost:3000/some/path', {
  firstName: 'hello',
  lastName: 'world'
});
```

Now the data can be seen in the server log.

```
$ node express_server.js
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
data from the client { firstName: 'hello', lastName: 'world' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I am already using express.json() and express.urlencoded(). I feel like it is about the structure of the data I am trying to post. In my question i have an array as a sample (blocks) Is there any chance if you can try to post it via axios on your set up? Because I really tried so many combinations, but for some reason I can't get the data on the server side. Btw, if I only send regular text, it is fine and everything is working as expected.

Comment: @Enes the array is serialized as expected. My setup works with the following request `axios.put('http://localhost:3000/some/path', { layouts: { lg: [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }] } });`

Comment: @Enes try putting `app.use(express.json())` at the top of your server code, just below the `const app = express()`.

Comment: I have tried it with the sample data you have tried : `{ layouts: { lg: [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }] } })` And it worked. Then, I have replaced it with my own data which is coming from a react State, and it failed. The data itself is good, because when i console it, everything seems fine. But for some reason, if i pass it to the axios, it fails. 

Is it ok to pass the data from the use state or should I do something before passing it? Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated !

Comment: Oh also the position of `app.use(express.json())` was already as you have mentioned.

Comment: Also, I get this error at console when I try to post my data through react state : `Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLButtonElement'
    |     property '__reactFiber$ez5jq1xogkp' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle`

I have tried to use Flatted for that reason before, but didn't change the results.

Comment: @Enes do you really need all the data you are passing to the server in the layouts? You can make it work if you remove the properties with circular references thus making the object convertible to JSON.